# Should I care if StreamWriter.Dispose() throws a System.IO.IOException?

Tags: .net

I'm using a StreamWriter to write to a file over the network (Samba).

Sometimes, the network conditions are not so good and causes my write to fail. In that case, I want to just clean up and try starting a new file.

The problem is that, even when I try to clean up (i.e. calling Dispose() on my StreamWriter object), I get an IOException as it fails to flush (because the network conditions are bad, remember), like so:

```
System.IO.IOException
An unexpected network error occurred.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
```

Shall I care in such case? If I catch the IOException, shall I then try to somehow finish the clean up in other ways? Or do I just ignore the IOException and move along?

In other words, what should I do here?

```
try
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(some_network_file_path, /* ... */))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            /* append lines of csv-style data to the file. */
        }
    }
}
/* writer.Dispose() can throw an IOException as it fails to flush. */
catch (System.IO.IOException)
{
    /*
    What shall I do here, if anything at all?
    Suppose that my only concern is resource leak via the StreamWriter
    object.
    It's easy for me to clean up the data file later by discarding the last
    incomplete line.
    */
}
```

Comment: why would you try to ignore an exception?If the flush is failing it is expected that you loose your data.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I'm not overly concerned about losing data. It's just lines of csv-style data anyway, I can just clean up the data later on by chopping off the last corrupted line. I don't really care about missing that last line.

What I'm concerned about is resource leak. If I try to Dispose() and I get an exception, the StreamWriter is in some sort of limbo, right? I can't write to it anymore and it's not completely disposed either.

Comment: A corrupt file was left on that network drive.  Armed and dangerous, anybody that reads it is going to be in for a very rude surprise, usually very hard to diagnose.  Yeah, don't ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

You should care about an error if you, well, *care* about:

- whether it happens or not, and
- the fact of it happening when it does.

The first thing to make clear for yourself here is *the cause(s) of the error and the resulting impact of it happening **or not happening** on your application.*

E.g. if your I/O failed, you sigh and think your data is lost. But, on connection close (if your deduction is correct), a flush is attempted again, and if there's no error this time, your data actually isn't lost.